# Date pick from iphone and save date as NSSTRING..and match both dates

Tags: iphone

I want to match date which i am pick from database and match it with iphone current date.How can i do.?

Answer (score 1):

first covert you string date into NSDate object then use as follows
for conversion in date object

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateForCompareObject = [dateFormat dateFromString:yourDataBaseDate];
[dateFormat release];
    NSDate *today=[NSDate date];



    if([dateForCompareObject compare:today]==NSOrderedAscending)
    {
       //your code
    }
    else if([dateForCompare compare:today]==NSOrderedDescending)
    {
      //your code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instance method of NSDate from documentation...

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

Check out the return type here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, uhm, the title sounds like you have your date in database as string? Well, then the first thing you need to do is to use the `NSDateFormatter` to get an `NSDate` object back.

To compare two NSDates you can simply call `[date compare:otherDate]` and use the return value.